# How to remove double checking when setting a value in a multithreaded environment

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, double-checked-locking

I have a class  `Checker` that stores the field `archiveDate`.There are several threads that can set this field. They only record the field if it is not yet available. And if one of the threads recorded the date, the other threads don't have to overwrite it. And there is another thread (the `Checker` itself) that can remove the date. It removes the date only if it is set. Now my code looks like this.

```
public class Checker extends Thread {
    private volatile LocalDateTime archiveDate;
    private ReentrantLock lock;

    public Checker() {
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            if (archiveDate != null) {
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    if (archiveDate != null && archiveDate.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now())) {
                        //do something
                        archiveDate = null;
                    }
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void changeDate(LocalDateTime date) {
        if (archiveDate == null) {
            lock.lock();
            if (archiveDate == null) {
                try {
                    archiveDate = date;
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can I avoid double checks or simplify the code in some way?

Comment: You need to move the lock.unlock() in the changeDate() method.  There exists the possibility that the lock will not be released with the current code.

Comment: You probably should be using `AtomicReference`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- and a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of manually waiting in 30 second chunks…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you are using the wrong tool for the job. To execute a task at a particular datetime, use an adapter to a `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
static final ScheduledExecutorService ES = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

public static ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(LocalDateTime targetTime, Runnable r) {
    return ES.schedule(r,
        LocalDateTime.now().until(targetTime, ChronoUnit.NANOS), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
}
```

To me, it looks a bit strange to ignore new requests when there is a pending one, regardless of the specified date, but a logic similar to your question’s code can be implemented using above `schedule` method as:

```
class Checker implements Runnable {
    final AtomicReference<LocalDateTime> archiveDate = new AtomicReference<>();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do something
    
        archiveDate.set(null);
    }

    public void changeDate(LocalDateTime date) {
        if(archiveDate.compareAndSet(null, date)) {
            schedule(date, this);
        }
    }
}
```